# Nginx PHP-FPM 5.6 PATH_INFO is empty

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

I'm running nginx 1.14.0 and php-fpm5.6 on Ubuntu 18.04. When I look at my PHP variables with info.php, the PATH_INFO variable is empty. I wonder what could be wrong?

*/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.conf*

```
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass php56; # upstream server named in /conf.d/default.conf
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 30;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
    fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
    fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;
    fastcgi_index index.php;

    # regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

    # Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
    # see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
    set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;



    # Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
    try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
}
```

*/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params*

```
fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING        $query_string;

fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD      $request_method;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI     $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_SCHEME      $scheme;

fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE        $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH      $content_length;

fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME     $fastcgi_script_name;

fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI        $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT       $document_root;

fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL     $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE     nginx/$nginx_version;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR     $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT     $server_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME     $server_name;

fastcgi_param   HTTPS           $https if_not_empty;
fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1;

fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR     $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT     $remote_port;

fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO       $path_info;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS     200;
```

*PHP Variables output*

```
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]    /var/www/vhosts/mysite/site
_SERVER["DOCUMENT_URI"] /server/info.php
_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]    no value
_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]  /var/www/vhosts/mysite/site/server/info.php
_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]  /server/info.php
```

Comment: What is the value of REQUEST_URI?

Comment: _SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] /server/info.php

Comment: I have a hunch the culprit is missing $fastcgi_path_info but I don't know why or how I could debug it

Comment: There is no path info. The path info is that part of the URI following the script name. So in `/server/info.php/foo/bar`, the `/foo/bar` is the path info.

Comment: That's it! :) I had misunderstood what path_info is.